# mod rewrite (css/images)

Tags: css, image, apache, mod-rewrite

im using the following to rewrite my urls:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html
```

the problem is this causes the css and images to not appear - is there a way that the rules can be excluded from folders like css and images folder so that the appear as they should instead of dead images and no css?
thanks Angel xx

Comment: Similar Question  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912412/htaccess-break-all-css-and-js-though-i-set-absolute-path

Comment: Looks like a type in the second `RewriteCond`.  Should you have a space before the `\.html`?

Comment: Can you show a CSS URL that doesn't work? What happens when you open it in your browser?

Answer (score 6):

**Best Practice:**

include all css / images and js files with
**absolute path** instead of **relative path** when you apply `.htaccess` for URL rewriting.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it unfortunately.

Comment: I've never had to do anything like that before. Can you explain your answer, why this must be done?

Comment: @wesley he is using `[R=301,L]` thats why? and this is best practice anyways

Comment: Sorry to assume, but I would think that it's not a requirement and the RewriteRule could be fixed. Something about that first one does not look right, but perhaps it's my lack of understanding. EDIT: In hindsight, I always use `/absolute/paths` anyways, so that would explain why I've never had an issue :D Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(css|images|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Substitute `css|images|js` by your folder names, separated by `|`

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Put your complete domain in your css link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" />
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.yourdomain.com/css/style.css" media="all" />
```

When using rewrite url's you get directories: `yoururl.com/dir/dir/item.html` making the paths in your html to the css files incorrect.

If you want to avoid this it's best to use complete paths to your css files. Your browser doesn't understand you are rewriting url's so it thinks that you are just browsing trough directories.

Comment: Is this really necessary? Can you explain?

Comment: Well when using rewrite url's you get directories: yoururl.com/dir/dir/item.html making the paths in your html to the css files incorrect. So the best way is to set a full path to your css files to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="all" />
```

To

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" media="all" />
```

"/" as root directory on your hosting. Similar with "/image/...".

Hope this helps...